# Find invariant subspace for the standard ordered basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Good evening,
I have a Matrix, $A$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & -1 \\
    2       & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
and I have shown that it only has invariant subspaces  of$ R^2$ and the zero subspace where T is a linear operator on $R^2$. 
My question is from Hoffman's linear algebra, and says that if U is a linear operator on $C^2$, 'the matrix of which in the standard ordered basis is A', show that U has $1-$dimensional invariant subspaces.
I am struggling in particular with the wording of the section in quotes, and how I proceed to answer this question,
Thanks in advance, Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he wants you to view the matrix in regard to a $\mathbb{C}$-linear operator on the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $\mathbb{C}^2$. "of which in the standard ordered basis is $A$" simply means to view the columns of $A$ as the images of the standard basis of $(1,0),\ (0,1)$.

Now in order to show that $U$ has an 1-dimensional invariant subspace, you will need to find a $v \in \mathbb{C}^2$ so that $U(v) = Av = \lambda v$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. So $\lambda$ will need to be an eigenvalue.
You will see that the characteristical polynomial of $A$ is $x^2-3x+4$ which does not have real roots. But it has complex roots, and the corresponding eigenvectors will give you your 1-dimensional invariant subspaces.